# SQL COUNT users with MIN date of login?

Tags: sql, count, min

I have a simple table of 3 users who logged into a website for the first time in October 2013. The following table shows individual logins for each user. In this case, the MIN login date is their date of first login.

```
| user | login_date |
  user1    10/3
  user2    10/3
  user1    10/4
  user3    10/14
  user2    10/15
  user3    10/20
```

So, to find users who logged in for the first time on 10/3, I use

```
SELECT user FROM table GROUP BY user HAVING MIN(login_date)='10/3';
```

However, how do I just COUNT those users, with the output being 2? So, COUNT unique users who have login_date='10/3'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT user
      FROM table
      GROUP BY user
      HAVING MIN(login_date) = '10/3'
     ) t
```

Your format for a date constant leaves something to be desired.  You might consider something like '2013-10-03', which should work in most databases.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. That's a clever way to user count(*). I appreciate your solution!

Answer (score 1):

How about

SELECT count(distinct(user)) FROM table GROUP BY user HAVING MIN(login_date)='10/3';

Comment: This will still return a separate row for each user.

Comment: Hi! Yes, your query returns a row for each user with how many times they appear in the list as the value... or something like that